# Removing n elements from array starting from index

Tags: c#, array

This method removes n elements starting from a given index, from an array of a given type. If n is positive it removes elements forwards, if it is negative it removes them backwards (e.g. for an array {1,2,3,4,5} Remove(2,2) results in {1,2,5}; Remove (2,-2) results in {1,4,5})

It there a better way to do it?

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] array, int idx, int len)
    {
        T[] newArray;

        if (len > 0)
        {
            if (idx + len > array.Length)
                len = array.Length - idx;

            newArray = new T[array.Length - len];
            if (idx > 0)
                Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 0, idx);

            if (idx < array.Length - 1)
                Array.Copy(array, idx + len, newArray, idx, array.Length - idx - len);
        }
        else
        {
            newArray = new T[array.Length + len];
            if (idx > 0)
                Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 0, idx + len);

            if (idx < array.Length - 1)
                Array.Copy(array, idx, newArray, idx + len, array.Length - idx);
        }            

        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth looking into `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` with Linq, you could condense quite a bit.

Comment: Using the index version of Linq's 'where', would be quite straight forward. 
array.where( (number, index) => index < startIndex || index > endIndex).ToArray(). Where startIndex and endIndex are precomputed and validated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that if the `len < 0`, it's better to adjust `idx` and `len` values. This will eliminate two branches of code.

Another suggestion is to use more readable variable names.
For instance, method arguments could be named `startIndex` and `length` respectively.

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

    if (length < 0)
    {
        startIndex += 1 + length;
        length = -length;
    }

    if (startIndex < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex");
    if (startIndex + length > array.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");

    T[] newArray = new T[array.Length - length];

    Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 0, startIndex);
    Array.Copy(array, startIndex + length, newArray, startIndex, array.Length - startIndex - length);

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On top of @Dmitry's  answer

This method wouldn't be easy to use IMO. Having the ability to pass a negative length is just not natural.

In addition you didn't validate the methods argument enough. Assume a passed in array which is having only one item is used with a `len ==-2` this would just blow in your face with an exception.

Comment: I don't agree. I think it's fine to specify a negative number to remove items before an item. It sound pretty natural to me.

Comment: @t3chb0t if you often e.g use `List <T>.RemoveRange ()` you wouldn't feel like that.

Comment: I agree with Heslacher. Passing negative values as `count` parameter might be natural in other languages (`Python` comes to mind), but it is definitely not something your average C# developer would instantly recognize and understand. To my knowledge there is not a single method in .Net framework which takes negative `count` and does not throw. If this functionality is a must for some reason, I would rather have some `RemoveBefore` method, which takes positive `count`, but removes items in the opposite direction.

Comment: If one believes that a negative length or count is not natural, then wouldn't an extension of that belief be that `startIndex` should refer to absolute index position and not be relative to the end with a negative count?

Comment: Pity the first point about negative length are overshadowing the very valid second point about argument validation.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is similar to [Dmitry's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132635/16139), but I will use LINQ and check the original startIndex and length.  I prefer to not mutate things if possible, especially parameters, even if they're value types, so that it's consistent with how you treat reference types.

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > array.Length - 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex");
    if (startIndex + length < 0 || startIndex + length > array.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");

    int newStartIndex = length >= 0 ? startIndex : (startIndex + 1 + length);
    int newLength = Math.Abs(length);
    return array.Take(startIndex).Concat(array.Skip(startIndex + length)).ToArray();
}
```

That will throw an exception if any of the skipped elements are outside of the array.  If you want, you can make your method like `Take()`, where it will remove the specified indexes in the array and ignore the specified indexes that are outside the array.

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

    int newStartIndex = length >= 0 ? startIndex : (startIndex + 1 + length);
    int newLength = Math.Abs(length);
    if(newStartIndex < 0)
    {
        newLength = Math.Max(newLength - newStartIndex, 0);
        newStartIndex = 0;
    }
    return array.Take(startIndex).Concat(array.Skip(startIndex + length)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess even without LINQ you could make several things better.

#### Code Logic suggestions

1) Regardless of the length's sign, the resulting array length is going to be the same. Thus this logic

```
    T[] newArray;
    if (len > 0)
    {
        newArray = new T[array.Length - len];
    }
    else
    {
        newArray = new T[array.Length + len];
    }
```

can be simplified to

```
    var newArray = new T[array.Length - Math.Abs(len)];
```

2) The code has kind of asymmetric parameter validation. You have the check for a positive case

```
    if (idx + len > array.Length)
        len = array.Length - idx;
```

but you do not have it for the negative case. In your example ({0,1,2,3,4}) I will see different behavior when calling

```
    array.RemoveAt(2, 4);
    array.RemoveAt(2, -4);
```

though actually doing similar things.

3) Also I would throw exceptions for all incorrect indexes and lengths. Look, here I am actually accessing similar non-existing place

```
    array.RemoveAt(4, 3);
    array.RemoveAt(6, 1);
```

but getting different behavior. First is considered to be OK, and second brings a .NET exception. Both reactions, imo, are not really nice.

4) Actually, I generally agree with Heslacher, negative length looks weird in C#. This feature is redundant because you can always just shift index in the method call. Simultaneously, logic becomes more complicated.

But if I desperately wanted to implement it, I would prefer to still have non-negative length and just add an enum parameter for direction with default value

```
    public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(
        this T[] array, 
        int idx, 
        int len, 
        Direction direction = Direction.Forward)
```

#### Code style suggestions

1) I support other responders about naming here, and also I would prefer "count" instead of "length" as it is done in the similar Microsoft [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx). And, well, RemoveRange is clearer then RemoveAt.

2) Also you should add braces around if bodies, here is some [reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces).

3) Also you could create two little methods with filling the resulting array to improve readability, e.g. FillLeftHalf() & FillRightHalf().

Comment: Nice answer.  I would add for the last item that the two little methods should be `private`.  Also might be overkill to have `Direction.Forward` enumeration when a simple bool would suffice.  I would name the bool `reverseDirection` so that the default value of false would mean forward.

Comment: @RickDavin Well, I though about simple bool but perhaps it is also not really in C# style. Compare to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx) method or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) one. Both use last bool param to slightly extend the logic of the method, not to change or switch it. But maybe there are other examples or this is just a question of taste.

Answer (score 3):

like @Greg said in his [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132630/removing-n-elements-from-array-starting-from-index#comment247581_132630) - you can make it really short with LINQ and you don't have to check any ranges:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int startIndex, int count)
{
    return
        count > 0
        ? items.TakeWhile((x, i) => i < startIndex).Concat(items.Skip(startIndex + count))
        : items.TakeWhile((x, i) => i < (startIndex + count + 1)).Concat(items.Skip(startIndex + 1));
}
```

Comment: `TakeWhile()` will ignore negative indexes, but `Skip()` will throw an exception for negative indexes, so you should be consistent and use `TakeWhile()` with `SkipWhile()` or `Take()` with `Skip()`.

Comment: Yeah, I realize now that mixing them here wasn't probably my best idea today ;-)

Comment: What I like best about this answer is your use of `IEnumerable<T>` rather than limiting it to just an array of `T[]`.  For simple looping, this is great and uses less memory, and the developer can always use a `.ToArray()` later if need be.